# Image from ImageReader is not the same as my preview surface

Tags: android, kotlin, surfaceview, android-camera2, image-reader

i wrote my image from ImageReader surface and got a very bad photo, is it the ratio ? they are all the same (w & h), is it something with TotalCaptureResult ? , please check the photo and code below, appreciate your help.

1- My original photo from SurfaceView (Screenshotted)

[SurfaceView holder.surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4bpF.jpg)

2- my output photo from my ImageReader Surface that i have targetted in my captureRequest.

[ImageReader surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TpU1.jpg)

3- check out my code, all codes in one function and i call this in the OnCreate.

code :

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
private fun camera() {




    val thread = HandlerThread("Hthread1").apply {
        start()
    }
    val handler = Handler(thread.looper).apply {
        post {


                //-------------------------------------------------


            val w = 1920
            val h = 1080
            val Rec = Rect(0,0,w,h)

            val imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(w,h,ImageFormat.YUV_420_888,4)

                val cm = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager

                val surfaceview = findViewById<SurfaceView>(R.id.surfaceView).apply {



                }



                surfaceview.holder.addCallback(object : SurfaceHolder.Callback {
                    override fun surfaceCreated(p0: SurfaceHolder) {



                        val surface = surfaceview.holder.surface
                           val surface2 = imageReader.surface
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                                applicationContext,
                                Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        ) {
                            requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), 777777)

                            return
                        }



                        cm.getCameraCharacteristics(cm.cameraIdList.last()).get(CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES)

                        cm.openCamera(
                            cm.cameraIdList.last(),
                            mainExecutor,
                            object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
                                override fun onOpened(p0: CameraDevice) {


                                    val cr =
                                        p0.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE)
                                            .apply {


                                                set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE,CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY)
                                                addTarget(surface2)
                                                addTarget(surface)

                                            }.build()




                                    p0.createCaptureSession(
                                        SessionConfiguration(SessionConfiguration.SESSION_REGULAR,
                                            mutableListOf(
                                                OutputConfiguration(surface),OutputConfiguration(surface2)
                                              ),
                                            mainExecutor,
                                            object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                                                override fun onConfigured(p0: CameraCaptureSession) {

                                                    p0.setRepeatingRequest(
                                                        cr,
                                                        object :
                                                            CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

                                                        },
                                                        null
                                                    )







                                                }

                                                override fun onConfigureFailed(p0: CameraCaptureSession) {

                                                }

                                            })
                                    )




                                }

                                override fun onDisconnected(p0: CameraDevice) {


                                }

                                override fun onError(p0: CameraDevice, p1: Int) {


                                }

                            })





                    }

                    override fun surfaceChanged(p0: SurfaceHolder, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {


                    }

                    override fun surfaceDestroyed(p0: SurfaceHolder) {


                    }

                })


                //-------------------------------------------------














    imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({
        val image = it.acquireLatestImage()

        if (image!=null) {

            val buffer = image.planes.last().buffer


            val byteArray = ByteArray(buffer.remaining())

            buffer.get(byteArray)
            val YuvImage = YuvImage(byteArray, ImageFormat.YUY2, w, h, null)


            findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
                val file = FileOutputStream(File.createTempFile("image", ".jpg", filesDir))
                YuvImage.compressToJpeg(Rec,85,file)

            }
            imageReader.discardFreeBuffers()
            image.close()
        }
    },null)


        }

    }
```

Edit: Tow photos one from ImageReader and the other a screenshot of the SurfaceView preview.

Comment: added original with reader output results for comparison

Comment: bro I have put it organised sorry for the mess.

Comment: I do not understand what your result picture has to do with the original. (and you posted a different original now).

Comment: Can you also format your code? All these empty lines....